# Converting roman numbers to integers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to convert roman numbers to integers but not able to figure out the errors in my code. It is showing this error **RangeError: Invalid array length**. Could anybody help me . Thanks in advance.

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  var arr = {'1':'I','5':"V",'10':"X",'50':"L",'100':"C",'500':"D",'1000':"M"} ;
  var result = "";
  var mult = 1;
  while ( num % 10 !== 0) {
    var n = num % 10 ;
    var h = n*mult;
    if( n < 4 ) {
      //console.log("eroor1-");
      result = Array(n+1).join(arr[h.toString()]) + result;
    }
    else if (n == 4) {
      //console.log("eroor2-");
      result = arr[(h-mult).toString()] + arr[h.toString()] + result;
    }
    else if(n == 5) {
      //console.log("eroor3-");
      result = arr[h.toString()] + result;
    }
    else if( n < 9 ) {
      //console.log("eroor4-");
      result = Array(n-4).join(arr[mult.toString()]) + result;
      //console.log("eroor4.1-");
      result = arr[h.toString()] + result;
    }
    else if(n == 9) {
     // console.log("eroor5-");
      result = arr[(h+mult).toString()] + arr[h.toString()] + result;
    }
    else {
      result = arr[h.toString()] + result;
    }

    mult *= 10;
    num = num / 10;
  }
 return result;
}

convertToRoman(36);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `arr` is an object and not an array. In order to take the next step in troubleshooting your code, you should either change it to an array or utilize it as an object